# TYPO3 - typoscript: Content Element Layout for Insert Records

Tags: typo3, typoscript

When I create a Content Element Layout:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout {
    removeItems = 1,2,3
    addItems.108 = Custom Layout
}
```

With an additional style:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
    key.field = layout
    108 = TEXT

    108.dataWrap = <div id="c{field : uid}" class="csc-default special">
    108.value = |</div>

    }

}
```

It won't work on a content element "Insert a Record" (A shortcut to another content element)

the data is not included.. I only receive a blank div

Comment: I have fixed it somehow by resetting the innerwrap.. it is not what i had in mind.. but for css it will do



    tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
        key.field = layout
        108 = TEXT
    
        108.dataWrap = <div id="c{field : uid}" class="csc-default special">
        108.value = |</div>
    
        }
        
    }
    tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap <

Comment: You can answer your own question with the solution you found, then the question can be marked "answered". This is helpful if someone else has this question, too.